# Coreplot plot space range - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot, scatter-plot

I'm trying to come up with a scatter plot whose range depends on the value received. The given variable self.xAxisMinimum takes in the first value of the data received. However when I run my program it reads such that, when self.xAxisMinimum  = 4688 the plotspace.range starts from 5000.
 Given below is the plotspace settings.

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange       

plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(self.xAxisMinimum - 100)  length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(60*60)];

plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yAxisMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yAxisMax - yAxisMin)];
```

Is it anything related to the the major interval length? I have major interval length of 180seconds. 
Give below is the code for the Xaxis-set's parameters.

```
axisSet.xAxis.title = @"Time(per sec)";
axisSet.xAxis.titleTextStyle = textStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.titleOffset = 30.0f;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.majorGridLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.minorGridLineStyle=gridStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.labelOffset = 6.0f;
axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(180.0f);
axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 5;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 0.50f;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 0.50f;
axisSet.xAxis.labelTextStyle = textStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.labelFormatter = formatter;
```

So for this set up I should have had a x axis starting from (4688-100) instead of 5000. Anyone have any idea why? thanks much in advance

Comment: What are your formatter settings? Is it rounding off the value to one significant digit? Have you inspected the actual `xRange` to see if it is being set correctly?

Comment: Hello Eric, the issue lies in DecimalFromFloat. I gave an integer input to the float value and converted into decimal. Instead I changed to DecimalFromInteger. It works fine. Thanks

Comment: @DesperateLearner: many thanks for posting your above comment: in my case, I had the same problem due to calling `CPTDecimalFromFloat` on a `double`. Your comment pointed me right at where to fix the problem. PS: you're encouraged to answer your own questions if you solve them yourself - if you post your comment as an answer, I'll be very happy to give you an upvote... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue lies in DecimalFromFloat. I gave an integer input to the float value and converted into decimal. Instead I changed to DecimalFromInteger. It works fine. Thanks